How to Unit Test a Nested Function Using PyTest Without Modifying the Outer Function
I have a Python function that contains a nested function. I want to write unit tests for the nested function using PyTest, but I don't want to modify the way the nested function is defined or its behavior. I also don't want to call or test the outer function itself, just the nested function.
Here is a simplified example of my code:
# example.py

def outer_function(a, b):
    """
    Example outer function that performs some operations.
    """
    def inner_function(x, y):
        """
        Nested function that I want to test.
        """
        return x + y
    
    # Some operations using inner_function
    result = inner_function(a, b)
    return result

I want to create a PyTest test function that only tests inner_function using parameterization, ensuring it covers various scenarios such as:

Adding two positive numbers
Adding positive and negative numbers
Adding two negative numbers
Adding zero to a number

How can I achieve this in a way that the tests are independent of outer_function?
Example Test Function:
# test_example.py

import pytest

@pytest.mark.parametrize("x, y, expected", [
    (1, 2, 3),         # Adding two positive numbers
    (1, -1, 0),        # Adding positive and negative numbers
    (-1, -2, -3),      # Adding two negative numbers
    (0, 5, 5),         # Adding zero to a number
    (3, 0, 3)          # Adding a number to zero
])
def test_inner_function(x, y, expected):
    """
    Describe how to test the inner_function here.
    """
    # Code to test inner_function goes here.

Any guidance or examples on how to properly structure and implement these tests would be greatly appreciated!

It doesn't seem like the inner function is an independent unit on its own. If it is, it shouldn't be nested; if it's nested then testing the outer function should suffice.

So, one of the main drawbacks of nested functions is that they are not unit testable. Or are not easy to unit test - as we shall see, it is possible.
One can't simply retrieve the function defined internally to another function, because it simply doesn't "exist" - the function object for the inner is created dynamically only when the outer function is executed, and the def statement (along with its body) is executed inside it.
If the outer function happens to return the inner function, then one can grab a reference to it, by calling the function. Even then, if the nested function does anything with nonlocal variables, one won't have control over those for testing.
And if it doesn't use nonlocal variables, i.e. variables local to the outer function scope, there is no reason for it to be a nested function to start with - one would be better off just refactoring the code so that the function is no longer nested.
Now - as I said, one can't retrieve the inner function itself at test time - but it is possible to retrieve the elements that "constitute" it, and recreate the inner function inside the test function, in a "clean room", so to say, and that one can be tested.
The function "core" itself on the other hand is a code object, which is generated at compile time (Python compilation is a transparent step prior to runtime, but it takes place). That one can be retrieved from the outer function's properties - and it can be used to recreate the inner function inside the test.
Some of the inner function elements however - namely its default parameters, are easier got if they are simply hard-coded on the test, instead of trying to introspect them from the outer function. (it is feasible, but through parsing the source code - it would be a whole different approach).
That said, creating a proper test becomes a matter of manipulating code ojects, types.FunctionType, and carefully prepare the nonlocal variables it may need in a nested function inside the test itself:

from types import FunctionType, CodeType

def outer_function(a, b):
    """
    Example outer function that performs some operations.
    """
    y = b
    def inner_function(x):  # "y" is not here! 
        """
        Nested function that I want to test.
        """
        return x + y  # <- included nonlocal variable, or the nested function is meaningless.

    # Some operations using inner_function
    result = inner_function(a)
    return result
...

@pytest.mark.parametrize("x, y_other, expected", [
    (1, 2, 3),         # Adding two positive numbers
    (1, -1, 0),        # Adding positive and negative numbers
    ...
])
def test_inner(x, y_other, expected):
    # Extract the code object. 
    # # filtering by  name is important because any comprehensions or lambda expressions
    # will also have code objects present in the outer function constants. 
    code_obj = [obj for obj in outer_function.__code__.co_consts if isinstance(obj, CodeType) and obj.co_name == "inner_function"][0]
    
    def closure_host():
        z = y_other # <- our variable that will take the place of "y" in the inner function
        def inner_fake():
            # fake inner function that uses the "z" nonlocal, so we can attach it to
            # our "sinthetic" inner function
            z  # that is it-  a single reference to the variable is enough
        return inner_fake
    
    closure = closure_host().__closure__
    func = FunctionType(code_obj, outer_function.__globals__, "inner_function", argdefs=(), closure=closure)
    assert func(x) == expected

The "argdefs" are the default arguments, and are the ones that, if present in the inner function definition, should be hardcoded back in the test.
I've renamed y to y_other in the test function so it can be clearly perceived that its name have no regards to the name of the variable inside the inner_function being tested.
What makes variable from the closure_host show up in the inner-function is the order they appear both in the inner_fake and inner_function bodies, as the closure is an ordinary tuple, the order of its elements is the only information Python uses to refer the nonlocal variables to their counterparts in the outerscope. That is, in source code, they have the same "name" - but once things are compiled into source code, those names are no longer used - and the order they show up is what counts. The contents of this closure tuple are extraordinary "cell" proxy objects, but that is another matter one doesn't need to care about in this scenario.

This is clever, although would probably never fly (not because of the test, but because of the code that required this test).  I'm curious about the idea that the nested function is meaningless without the non-local variable. If we don't actually return the inner function, isn't it still meaningless? After all, we just turn around and call the code so we might as well just replace the inner function call with the code. I'm trying to imagine a situation where it isn't meaningless and having trouble coming up with anything.

if you are not making any use of variables from the surrounding function in the inner function, then it is just an ordinary function which could be non nested, and the code would just work, without any other modification - but testing it would then be trivial. As described in the answer: this path is preferable.

Now, if the function does make use of the surrounding context, it might be useful in several ways . One of which is if it needs to run more than once during the lifetime of the outer function - having its code inlined in the function would be just repeating oneself and getting error prone. Or could be a generator - you can[ t just inline a generator code.  There are several situations where a nested function could be useful - a bit less when one consider that most nonlocal variables that make the nested function a thing can just be passed as parameters to an ordinary sibling function.

Thank you so much for the detailed response to the question

@Mark: just remembered these extra use cases: actually the place I personaly do use nested functions the most is, ironically, in test functions - if I am to simulate a scenario of multi-threading, or multi-asyncio tasks running, I prefer to write the code to go inside the workers in nested functions inside the test itself.

As stated in @Mark's comment, if a function is nested then it shouldn't be separated from the outer function. That's the whole point of nested functions. Most inner functions may not even work without the outer function (think, a nonlocal variable). However, if you really want to do this, there are multiple ways, but all of them need at least some bit of modification of your outer function's code. The first method is to return the inner function in the outer function along with any other original values that the outer function may return:
def outer_function(a, b):
    """
    Example outer function that performs some operations.
    """
    def inner_function(x, y):
        """
        Nested function that I want to test.
        """
        return x + y
    
    # Some operations using inner_function
    result = inner_function(a, b)
    return result, inner_function

res, inner = outer_function(1, 2)
@pytest.mark.parametrize("x, y, expected", [
    (1, 2, 3),  # Adding two positive numbers
    (1, -1, 0),  # Adding positive and negative numbers
    (-1, -2, -3),  # Adding two negative numbers
    (0, 5, 5),  # Adding zero to a number
    (3, 0, 3)  # Adding a number to zero
    ])
def test_inner(x, y, expected):
    assert inner(x, y) == expected)


In the above code, I replaced the decorator with a function call. A second approach to this would be to set an attribute of the outer function to the inner function:
def outer_function(a, b):
    """
    Example outer function that performs some operations.
    """
    def inner_function(x, y):
        """
        Nested function that I want to test.
        """
        return x + y
    
    # Some operations using inner_function
    result = inner_function(a, b)
    outer_function.inner = inner_function
    return result

res, inner = outer_function(1, 2), outer_function.inner
@pytest.mark.parametrize("x, y, expected", [
    (1, 2, 3),  # Adding two positive numbers
    (1, -1, 0),  # Adding positive and negative numbers
    (-1, -2, -3),  # Adding two negative numbers
    (0, 5, 5),  # Adding zero to a number
    (3, 0, 3)  # Adding a number to zero
    ])
def test_inner(x, y, expected):
    assert inner(x, y) == expected)

Remember, functions in Python are first-class, so you can just treat them like simple objects that can have a new attribute attached to them. In this case, I attached a reference of the inner function to the outer function, so there's no need to return the inner function as in the first approach. Outside of the outer function, just use the dot notation to fetch the inner function object after calling the outer function first (required here, because without calling the outer function first the outer_function.inner attribute would not be initialized).

Note: In both approaches, the pytest decorator must be called manually since the object we have outside is a reference to the inner function. Decorators must occur at the function definition, not just a function object.

This is nice - although requiring the outer function to be modified and called - which are "no go"s for the O.P. is simpler for a lot of cases than the approach on my answer.
Just note, however, that what should be decorated with pytest.mark.parametrize should not be inner itself - instead, a test would require a plain function, the one to be decorated, which retrieves the inner by calling the outer fuction, and then calls this inner and asserts the results for each case.

The question title says "Without Modifying the Outer Function" and you're modifying the outer function.

@nosteponsnek Yeah, but there's no way to achieve what OP wants without any modification to the outer function's code. If you can think up of one, please post as another answer so that me and everyone else can learn from it.

@LukeL - I am no downvoter - but it might be due to the incorrect usage of the pytest.mark.parametrize as I pointd out. Or it could be because you didn't answer what the O.P. asked for. As for "without modifying the outer function", please check my answer: it does exactly that - it just introspects the outer function.

(there, I edited your question so that pytest.mark.parametrize is used in the correct form. I had to do that, or I' end up downvoting you myself :-)  ) - you may want to adjust your text, as the decorator has to apply to the test function, not to the Function being tested - so there is no need (or sense) in applying it to inner using the call syntax.

"but there's no way to achieve what OP wants without any modification to the outer function's code" that's not true, as other answers already showed. Anyway, if you were permitted to refactor the code, we can do much better than the approaches in this answer show- it would be cleaner just to move the inner function to outside, and test/call it explicitly passing in any closure variables it was using previously.
